# How do you handle log rolling (or truncation) for unix services that don't handle it themselves?

Tags: unix, log-files

In my particular case it's the mysql general log and slow query log; neither is critical to operations, just there for troubleshooting if need be, and mysql doesn't have a mechanism for rolling or truncating either of them.  These logs can grow ridiculously large if neglected.  Is there a nice little cron-job+bash-script hack for rolling or truncating these files?  Thanks.

Comment: The references to cron, etc. imply *nix but please add the appropriate tag so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming Linux/Unix, logrotate

See: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-rotate-log-files/